Programmatically change data sensitivity level (security classification) of field in Standard Object
Is there a way to programmatically change the SecurityClassification property of a field? Referred to as Data Sensitivity Level as well in the docs: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=platform.data_classification_metadata_fields.htm&type=5
I am specifically looking to change a Standard Field (the Description of a Task). Changing this for a Custom Field through xml files works, but for a Standard Field doesn't. Is there a way to do this with Apex classes maybe?
Update: to clarify, my usecase is for shipping this with a 2nd generation package update. Using the metadata API to deploy this change in a single org works, however it's not suitable for our needs.
